# How can I get class's value which same classes are repeated?

Tags: javascript, html

Inside of my html, I have values like this

```
<div class="item" onClick="getcoordinates()">
    <div class="coordinate">
        0.1, 0.3
    </div>
<div>
<div class="item" onClick="getcoordinates()">
    <div class="coordinate">
        0.2, 0.4
    </div>
<div>
....
```

Those are repeatedly generated by django web service.

I want to get coordination which user clicked. For instance, if user clicked 0.2, 0.4 area, I want to get 0.2, 0.4 string.

However, *document.getElementsByClassName('coordinate');* returns array not a specific coordination.

How can I get a specific string which user clicked?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The minimal-modification approach to your code is to pass `this` into the function, which will be the DOM element for that specific `div`:

```
<div class="item" onClick="getcoordinates(this)">
```

Then in the function, use `.querySelector` on the `div` to find its `.coordinates` element, and read `innerHTML` from that:

```
function getcoordinates(div) {
    var coords = div.querySelector(".coordinates").innerHTML;
    // ...use coords....
}
```

You'll probably need to trim some whitespace off that. Modern browsers have a `trim` method on strings, which can be shimmed if needed, so:

```
var coords = div.querySelector(".coordinates").innerHTML.trim();
```

The shim is trivial:

```
if (!String.prototype.trim) {
    String.prototype.trim = function() {
        return this.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g, '');
    };
}
```

Or if you don't like modifying `String.prototype`, make a utility function:

```
function trimString(str) {
    if (str.trim) {
        return str.trim();
    }
    return str.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g, '');
}
```

and then

```
var coords = trimString(div.querySelector(".coordinates").innerHTML);
```

---

FWIW, I'd explore moving away from `onClick` attributes and toward using modern unobtrusive techiques, but the above should sort out this specific issue.

Comment: Thanks that's what I found! Since I'm noob about js, I cannot assure that 'this' operator's usage. Is that exists for objects or what? That is quite ambiguous to me.

Comment: @Sogo: `this` is a bit tricky in JavaScript. It's a keyword (not an operator) that acts a lot like a variable, but you can't assign a value to it. The value of `this` is set when you call a function (or when the global code is started by the JavaScript engine). More in my blog: [*Mythical methods*](http://tinyurl.com/nqwhvx9) and [*You must remember `this`*](http://tinyurl.com/qza4zge). The reason the `onClick="getcoordinates(this)"` above works is that when calling the code in the `onClick` attribute, the browser sets `this` to refer to the DOM element the attribute is on.

Answer (score 1):

You can edit your `onclick` attribute to be like `onclick="getcoordinates(this)"`. To get the string inside, you can have:

```
function getcoordinates(element) {
  var str = element.querySelector('.coordinate').innerText;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are missing the closing div tags, please add them.

```
  <div class="item" onclick="getcoordinates(this)">
    <div class="coordinate">
      0.1, 0.3
    </div>
  </div> <!-- missing -->
  <div class="item" onclick="getcoordinates(this)">
    <div class="coordinate">
      0.2, 0.4
    </div>
  </div> <!-- missing -->



function getcoordinates(obj) {
  alert(obj.innerText);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion this is the best way to do it. On the other hand my opinion is bubkas, and onClick will also work if you use Mahesh Sapkal's method with this.getElementsByClassName.

```
<div class="item">
    <div class="coordinate">
        0.1, 0.3
    </div>
</div>
<div class="item">
    <div class="coordinate">
        0.2, 0.4
    </div>
</div>
<script>
var items = document.getElementsByClassName('item');
for(var i=0; i<items.length; i++){
    items[i].addEventListener('click', function(){
        //Use querySelector for an easier current method.
        //console.log(this.querySelector('.coordinate').innerHTML);
        //getElementsByClassName works.
        console.log(this.getElementsByClassName('coordinate')[0].innerHTML);
    });
}
</script>
</body>
```

By the way. You really should use your closing tags.